# Find the 1st intersection of 2 PDF functions with Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

With Mathematica 8.0.1.0, I have used `FindRoot[]` to identify the intersection of two 2 pdf functions.

But if I have pdf functions that intersect at more than one point, and I have the upper limit of the x axis range beyond the second intersection, `FindRoot[]` only returns the second intersection.

```
pdf1 = 1/x 0.5795367855565214` (E^(
  11.170058830053032` (-1.525439351903338` - Log[x]))
   Erfc[1.6962452696714152` (-0.5548887795964352` - Log[x])] + 
 E^(1.2932713057519` (2.60836043407439` + Log[x]))
   Erfc[1.6962452696714152` (2.720730943938539` + Log[x])]);

pdf2 = 1/x 0.4648445097126269` (E^(
  5.17560914275408` (-2.5500941338198615` - Log[x]))
   Erfc[1.7747318880142482` (-2.139288893723375` - Log[x])] + 
 E^(1.1332542415053757` (3.050849516581922` + Log[x]))
   Erfc[1.7747318880142482` (3.1407996592474956` + Log[x])]);

Plot[{pdf1, pdf2}, {x, 0, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All]   (* Shows 1st intersection *)
Plot[{pdf1, pdf2}, {x, 0.4, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All] (* Shows 2nd intersection *)

{x /. FindRoot[pdf1 == pdf2, {x, 0.00001, 0.5}],
x /. FindRoot[pdf1 == pdf2, {x, 0.00001, 0.4}]}
```

[image]
[image]

The above plots show the issue.  When plotted they intersect at two points:

```
{0.464719, 0.0452777}
```

respectively.

As I can't know before hand if I'll have a second intersection and I don't know where it might fall on the x axis if I did, can anyone suggest a way to have `FindRoot[]` only return the first intersection rather than the second?

If not, can anyone suggest another way to go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `FindRoot[]`, you can only get a single root for a given starting point. Iterating through different options is cumbersome and you might not even get the desired result for certain edge cases unless you hit upon the right choice of starting point.

In this case, something like `NSolve` or `Reduce` might be a better option. If you know that your expressions decay, using a reasonable upper bound for possible values of `x`, you can use the following, which is pretty quick and will give you *all* roots.

```
NSolve[{pdf1 == pdf2, 0 < x < 1}, x] // Timing
Out[1]= {0.073495, {{x -> 0.0452777}, {x -> 0.464719}}}
```

Comment: I've come away with two ways to address the issue.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

First you have to find all roots in one step. I do this with

```
roots=Reduce[pdf1==pdf2&&0.000001<x<0.5,x]
```

And then you could take the minimum (first root on the x axis in your special case).

```
rootMin=Min[N[x/.{ToRules[roots]}]]
```

Comment: Both solutions offered (yours and yoda's) work.  Many thanks for your suggestion, it just seems that yoda's works the tinniest bit better in my application.